# Find all a, b, c, d, e, such that a + b + c + d + e = 1000 with no more than 3 loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm

One of my friend gave this problem and I am try to find a best solution for this. The requirements is:

- a,b,c,d,e is an integer from 0 to 1000, no relation between a, b, c, d, e so a can equal to b or c, ...
- can not use more than 3 loops (it can be 3 nested loop or 3 normal loop, or 2 nested loop + 1 normal loop, ...)
- you need to find all the answers for (a, b, c, d, e) and:

```
a + b + c + d + e = 1000
```

The basic way, we will do some thing like this: Loop all a, b, c, d, e with value from 0 to 1000 and then if sum of them is 1000, we print it, so we will have 5 loops.

I implemented a solution in Python here that used 5 loops: https://repl.it/repls/BestKnobbyDonateware

Can you find the way to solve this problem with 3 loops?

**UPDATE:**

This way is my solution:

[image: img]

It is not the homework, it is just a interesting question that I want to know what other developers will resolve this.

Note:

Try not using any hidden loops like initialization to a range,

but Sum and other mathematical list operations don't count as loops as long as you are using them on a relatively small set of elements.

Generating permutations of such small elements will be considered a single loop if using a function.

Comment: @Teemu, I need an algorithm and you can use any language

Comment: Maybe ask on [codegolf.se]? It's called "programming puzzles", you may get more help there.

Comment: I have a `O(1)` solution to this. Not a single loop needed. a = 1000 and rest are 0, You haven't specified any equality relationships between a,b,c,d and e.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni, I updated my post, you need to find all answers for each a, b, c, d, e

Comment: 3 loops deep or 3 loops in total?

Comment: is it a requirement that a, b, c, d and e to have different values?

Comment: @shukiavraham, Ahmad, I updated my post, can you take a quick look about it, thanks!

Comment: I have a solution for you but the question is on hold. the main idea is to split it like a tree, 1000 = x+y, x=a+b, y=c+d

Comment: this is a strange question, smells like homework... The limit on loops is an odd requirement. Isn't it more interesting to ask for the most efficient algorithm?

Comment: @shukiavraham  so 1000 = x+y+e, but to find a and b or c and d you still need a loop. How can my question get reopened without On Hold?

Comment: Here's a hint: your program does at least a thousand times too much work because there is at most one value of `e` which will produce a valid tuple. Once you have `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, you can easily compute the value of `e` which will produce the sum 1000; then you only need to check if that value is in range. Shuki avraham's solution takes that observation to one more level.

Comment: Anyway, i think the most efficient thing is to always assume a > b > c > d > e. (you can then use symmetry to generate the permutations). Then you do four loops, such as `for(a=1000; a>=200; a--) for(b=min(1000-a, a);b>=0;b--) for(c=min(1000-a-b,b);c>=0;c---)`. Dont forget to set e = 1000-a-b-c-d.

Comment: You could get away with one loop. Treat the problem where each field is a digit in a larger number where the base is 1000. Count up through each digit and carry if you ever hit the max. There would be 1000^5 combinations to check though. Implemented a solution but don't know how to share it

Comment: This way is my solution: https://i.imgur.com/oggOJ1A.png

It is not the homework, it is just a interesting question that I want to know what other developers will resolve this.

@MateuszSiniarski: can we share with us your code , you can make it by any text paste service online like gist.github.com

Comment: If n is the sum and m is the amount of categories to put them into, then the amount of solutions is exactly n+m-1 choose m-1 ( in other words (n+m-1)!/(n!*(m-1)!)). This comes from combitorics, where we can consider it as the way to divide n balls into m groups. We do this by choosing m-1 group separators, which must be must be placed between elements, and we do not distinguish between different orderings. If we add m-1 balls to the n balls,  we just have to chose m-1 balls as separators, then there is exactly n balls left, which forms the desired ordering, and with the above result following.

Comment: @chaugiang Here you go, had fun with this one https://github.com/siniarski/sum5Puzzle

Comment: @MateuszSiniarski, thank for your answer, I just star it and if you want to check another funny solution you can go here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187871/find-all-a-b-c-d-e-such-that-a-b-c-d-e-1000-with-no-more-than-3-l

Comment: Just use recursion, and only a single loop.